# Differences between 'must'

Tags: word-choice

Is there any significant difference between ～ないと、～なきゃ、なくちゃ when they mean 'must'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～ないと is usually used for rules, social conventions, very important appointments, and is often abbreviated to just ～ないと.  (with no explanatory clause following)

運動をしないとね  = Undou wo shinai to ne / 'Cause if you don't work out, then... = "gotta work out"

手を洗わないとね = gotta wash your hands.  (to me personally it feels more like "yeah because if you don't wash your hands then...")

～なきゃ feels colloquial (and in some cases hurried)

～なくちゃ feels colloquial

～なくてはいけません (roughly: must do this at all costs")