# What is the difference in nuance between しなきゃ and しないと

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances

Obviously, なきゃ is the short/casual form of なければならない like in:
病院へ行かなきゃ。
I need to go to the hospital.

But I've also seen negative + と be used to express the same thing.
病院へ行かないと。

I assume と here is conditional but is a difference in nuance between the two? Or are they both interchangeable?

Comment: They are mostly interchangeable: [Differences between 'must'](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24353/45489)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, ～しなきゃ is more informal. It is usually wise to avoid しなきゃ unless you're talking with your friends (although this depends on your age and personality). ～しないと is not particularly formal, but it's polite enough when you are conversing with a stranger or your boss.

More generally, the [eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010) is considered highly colloquial or informal.